# Best practice for handling validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a UI with some set of fields where a field becomes mandatory based on value inserted in other field. So just wanted to know the best practice whether this validation needs to be done at server side as well as UI end or its enough if I do the validation at UI end but not at server end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be checks on both the client side and the server side.

The client should not be able to submit an incomplete form.

And if another frontend is ever developped, in let's say a webpage, the developer might forget to enforce the checks. The back-end then needs to be able to handle and reject an invalid form.

Answer (score 1):

The rule with validation is never trust input. Assuming that you are building a web application you should at the very least validate when you first hit the server and report errors quickly. The reason being that user's behave unexpectedly and client-side javascript is easily subverted. Client side javascript should be viewed as a convenience for the user. If you expose your services on many fronts (thick client, web services, etc.) then you should also validate in your services.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to validate this at UI, when you are not using any framework. This will improve the responsiveness for your customer.
Validation on server side is also necessary if you need consistent data in your database.

Perhaps, think of using a framework like Java Server Faces

Answer (score 0):

Frontend validation is easy to implement and the user gets a fast response to his actions. You will need this.

If you wanna persist or do some logic in the backend you should also validate it in the backend.

Java/JSF hibernate Example (backend):

```
@NotBlank(message = "{contact.firstName.isEmpty}")
@Size(min = 1, max = 255, message = "{contact.firstName.invalid}")
public String getFirstName() {
     return firstName;
}
```